# How to access camera in Blackberry Playbook using Adobe Air SDK( in Flash builder Burrito)

Tags: blackberry, air, blackberry-playbook

In my application , if i click a button, camera mode want to load, take picture and need to upload in server.

Is it possible? If it is, Provide me some sample codings pl.

Am using Adobe Air SDK ( in Flash builder Burrito ) for development.

With regards,

Sampath

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can't access Blackberry camera with AIR. This API is still under development by blackberry.

The only mobile OS you can access camera with AIR is Android 2.2 with AIR 2.5 installed.